# Why is VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(lbi) == 0?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get my ToggleButton from a DataTemplate

```
ListBoxItem lbi = this.UnitsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as ListBoxItem;
```

lbi is ok (not null).

I would like to do this:

```
ContentPresenter cp = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lbi, 0) as ContentPresenter;
ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cp, 0);
```

But

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(lbi) is 0.
```

This is my XAML

```
<ListBox  MaxWidth="215" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="UnitsListBox" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" SelectionChanged="UnitsListBox_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Button"/>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate  >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="UnitSidebarButton"  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="60" Width="60"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"  Margin="0" Padding="0" Checked="UnitSidebarButton_Checked" Unchecked="UnitSidebarButton_Unchecked" Focusable="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cIMSidebarConverter2}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>
                          </Grid>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Are you making sure the containers have been generated before running your code?

Comment: @Rachel I think they are guaranteed to be generated since lbi is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied/pasted your code into a test project, the next item in the visual tree hierarchy below the `ListBoxItem` was a `Border` element, not a `ContentPresenter` (I use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to view the Visual Tree). I suspect that is why your `ContentPresenter` object is null.

If you're interested, I have some [VisualTreeHelpers](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) on my blog that would probably make this easier. You can use them like this:

```
var toggleBtn = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<ToggleButton>(lbi);
```

---

(**Old Answer**)

Your containers are probably not generated

Here's an example of how to use the `StatusChanged` event to identify if the containers have been generated or not before running your code

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Attach StatusChanged event
    UnitsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += 
        ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
}

void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If containers have been generated
    if (UnitsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == 
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        // Remove event
        UnitsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= 
            ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;

        // Do whatever here
        var lbi = UnitsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as ListBoxItem;

    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code, my containers were generated.  It did not fix the problem. VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lbi, 0) as ContentPresenter == null (still).

Comment: @iterationx In that case, I am guessing the control below your `ListBoxItem` isn't a `ContentPresenter`. I copied/pasted your code into a text project and looked at the output, and it looks like the next item in the hierarchy is a `Border`, not the `ContentPresenter`. If you're interested, I have some [helper classes](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) on my blog that make searching the Visual Tree for a specific object much easier.